# Is there a way to know which element in css file is used in html?

Tags: html, css

Example scenario.

You got a full HTML code from your friend. In HTML which you got, there are various 3rd party css package.

let's say one of them is animate.css. you can find link markup and easily find your friend use animate.css package.

```
<link href="vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

but I wonder if animate.css was really used. There are lots of elements in animate.css. I can't check every single element in HTML to find out if it uses a selector for a animate.css element.

portfolio-carousel, owl-carousel, owl-theme class selector are easy to figure out. But what about wow, fadeIn? Is it from 3rd css file or css my friend made himself?

```
<div class="portfolio-carousel wow fadeIn owl-carousel owl-theme">
```

Is there any way to figure out css files are really using with tools and which selectors for which css files are used?? Because I want to remove css link line in a code which I got from others if it is not used.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome you can press f12

then click [click in the corner left arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKo4I.png) to select the element you want to inspect

then in the right of developers tools you will see
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPWMb.png)

the: all.css?somerandomversion:1

where that "1" is the line of code in the file where you should make that change